# Confusion on deleting channels

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm having issues with trying to get my Discord bot to delete channels (specifically vocal ones). I'm confused on how I should actually do the deletion of a specific channel chosen by the user

My code:

```
if (command === "p-close") {
  const m = await message.channel.send("Preparing to close the party..");

  const guild = message.guild;
  let [name] = args; //Get the channel name
  channel.delete('Deleting the party')
    .then(deleted => console.log(`Deleted ${deleted.name} to make room for new channels`))
    .catch(console.error);

  m.edit(`The party ${name} has been closed.`);
}
```

This doesn't seem to be working for me, and so that is why I've come here. Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using it like this:

```
const channel = message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === name)
```

Comment: If that solved your problem, can you accept this answer by clicking on the tick on the left? That will both mark your question as solved and give reputation to the author ;)

Comment: Haha, yeah sorry I forgot to do that. I've not use stack that much.